# jquery get father of element

Tags: jquery

I've got an element which resides inside a div. I'd like to get the div by the child's ID, is this possible? if so how?

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("#id").parent()
```

My first suggestion `#id:parent` doesn’t work as [`:parent`](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selects all nodes that are parent of other nodes (including text nodes).

Answer (score 2):

If you are not looking for the immediate parent, you can also use:

```
$('#childID').closest("tr");
```

Where tr is a selector for the parent you're trying to find. This is useful if you aren't sure of the depth of the hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `parent` method of jQuery:

```
$("#myChild").parent()
```

You can even give it a selector if the parent element you're looking for is not the direct parent:

```
$("#myChild").parent(".container")
```

There's a slew of functions that help you traverse the DOM, and you can find detailed information in the [jQuery reference](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/).

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery to get the child element, and jQuery to address the parent

```
element = $('#childID').parent();
```

Note: Yes, this is similar to Pekka's answer. It was meant to be humorous in that regard. If you don't find it humorous.....

Answer (score 1):

I agree:

```
  $("#id").parent()
```

Is the best method. I had this issue the other day, but was quickly resolved. I realize this was already answered but I am new. And if I had been awake! pow pow! the answer would have flown out. **I'd appreciate an upvote**

BTW: here is a great new reference for jQuery http://jqapi.com/

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery to get the child element, and standard JS to address the parent:

```
element = $('#childID')[0].parentNode
```

Comment: To use this method, you need the `[0]`: `$('#childID')[0].parentNode`

Comment: Cheers Doug, I'm still mixing up Prototype and JQuery in my head. :)