# jQuery: How to get div where an element is contained?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to get the id of div where the input is contained, for example:

```
<div id="example">
    <label for="i1">Label1</label>
    <input id="i1" name="i1" type="text"/>
</div>
```

I hope can help me!

Comment: It's been already answered there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168254/jquery-get-father-of-element

Comment: Sure! if u post ur answer, I have accepted your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the `:has()` selector:

```
$('div:has("input")').attr('id')
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/TKNEG/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input').on('click', function(){

    alert($(this).parent().attr('id'));

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean:

```
$("div:has('input')").attr("id");
```

Or

```
$("div").has('input').attr("id");
```